# How to check if bytes are received from the client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-3.5, python-sockets

I am making a chat interface, and currently, the server has to send a message first in order for the chatting to work.

If the client sends a message first, then the server cannot see the message until the server sends a message to the client.

My question:

1. How can I check if the client has sent anything to me? Then I can simply print it out.

Here is the server code:

```
serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(("", 8080))
serv.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = serv.accept()

    print("Connection recieved from", addr)
    while True:
        strig = str(input("Enter your message to the client: "))
        c.send(strig.encode())

        thing = c.recv(1024)
        message = list(str(thing))
        message.remove("b")
        printable = ""

        for item in message:
            printable += item
        print(printable)

        strig = str(input("Enter your message to the client: "))
        c.send(strig.encode())

        thing = c.recv(1024)
        message = list(str(thing))
        message.remove("b")
        printable = ""

        for item in message:
            printable += item
        print(printable)
```

And here is the client code:

```
from time import sleep
s = socket.socket()

port = 8080

s.connect(("10.0.0.92", port))
while True:
    thing = str(s.recv(1024))
    message = list(thing)
    message.remove("b")
    #message.remove("/")
    printable = ""
    for item in message:
        printable += item
    print(printable)

    your = str(input("Enter your message to the server: "))
    s.send(your.encode())

    thing = str(s.recv(1024))
    message = list(thing)
    message.remove("b")
    #message.remove("/")
    printable = ""
    for item in message:
        printable += item
    print(printable)

    your = str(input("Enter your message to the server: "))
    s.send(your.encode())
```

Thanks in advance!!

p.s. I want one person to be the server, and one person to be the client. Please don't tell me to make both people clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is single-threaded.  `input` waits for input so will never get to `recv` without user input.  Create a thread to read client input and a thread to ask for and send messages.  You'll need something similar on the client side.